# To perform Grouping in Excel sheet

Tags: c#

I am creating a web application using C#.net. I'm using a hierarchical grid to show the reports. It means that,the outer grid contains the Currency code and the Total alone. By clicking the Expand icon from the outer grid an inner grid will be obtained showing the detailed list of the total. This is easily shown in the HTML View. Now i need to show the same result in the Excel sheet. At first it should show only the outer value. By clicking the Expand icon the detailed value should be obtained. How to perform this in Excel.

Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some discussion regarding this problem check them out

```
this.Application.get_Range("data2001", missing)
.Group(missing, missing, missing, missing);
```

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/6f692216-8a1f-4ecf-afe4-98c2a0957e11/
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53z7w54a.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2346759/group-rows-of-excel-using-csharp.aspx